# HP 2.4GHz Wireless Mouse not responsive after upgrade to ubuntu 17.10

Tags: upgrade, mouse, 17.10

I did an upgrade from 17.04 - 17.10 and immediately after that i haven't been able to use my mouse again. its a HP 2.4GHz wireless mouse and i have changed the battery and also switched the dongle between all the available ports yet no response.

Is there a fix for this .

Answer (score 0):

You may try switching back to Unity, as I did. That solved a lag I observed in my mouse's movement. It seems like Gnome doesn't like my hardware.

Here's a how to:
https://itsfoss.com/use-unity-ubuntu-17-10/